# relative entropy and free energy used to deduce the stochastic game between an agent and the market.

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, finance

I am reading the article *Pricing via utility maximization and entropy* by Richard Rouge and Nicole El Karoui. They talk about the *relative entropy* of a probability measure $Q$ with respect to the probability measure $P$ defined by $h(Q \vert P) := E[dQ/dP \ln(dQ/dP)]$ if $Q \ll P$, $+\infty$ else. They also talk about the concept of *free energy* of a random variable $B$, and this is equal to $\ln E[\exp B]$. They claim that for a bounded random variable $B$, entropy and free energy are in relation by the following duality:

\begin{align}
\ln  E[\exp B] = \sup_{Q \ll P} [ E^{Q}[B] - h(Q \vert P) ]
\end{align}

Does anyone know an article that shows the proof? or does anyone have any idea about how to deduce this equation? It may sound trivial, but I haven't seen a supremum in this way.

The interesting feature is that with this formula we can deduce the stochastic game between an agent and the market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result about the [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate) of the map $Q \mapsto h(Q \mid P)$.

[Here is a proof for discrete random variables](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/29228/a-question-on-convex-conjugate-duality-for-kl-divergence) (note that $P$ and $Q$ are defined opposite to yours), which I believe can be generalized.